# SQL query multiple joins too slow

Tags: mysql, join

This is my SQL query, takes about 3-4 seconds. Using Yii2.

```
SELECT `hotel`.* FROM `hotel` 
INNER JOIN `term` ON term.hotel_ID=hotel.ID 
INNER JOIN `airport_term` ON airport_term.term_ID=term.ID 
INNER JOIN `airport` ON airport.ID=airport_term.airport_ID 
WHERE `airport`.`name` IN ('Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Prague') 
GROUP BY `hotel`.`ID` 
ORDER BY `rating` DESC
```

Explained query: https://pastebin.com/niEqrM5M

Show create table: https://pastebin.com/Ws6yH3P5

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is: select hotels which terms have airport Vienna

hotel: 12k records, term: 290k records, airport_term: 200k items, airport: 30 items

Is there some way to make this query faster? I already did indexes on those tables.

Comment: just wondering, if it helps that you start from airport table first and then join other tables until you reach hotel table. WHERE clause is on airport table; it will help in minimizing the number of records to look for.

Comment: Looking at the EXPLAIN, the airport_term lookup is the main problem. Didn't you indexed airport_id on that table?

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables. Note also, (as others have mentioned) that your GROUP BY clause does nothing useful here, and should be omitted.

Comment: Is the value 'Vienna' a parameter or a single hardcoded value? Is it possible to break the query into multiple lines? Because I seriously don't see the nees to join the airport table if its a single value

Comment: Sorry, my first question. Added show create table. Group by is neccesary, otherwise I get duplicates of hotel. There can be more airports than Vienna, one term can have multiple airports.

Comment: I need to start from the hotel table, airport is just one of the filters. I have problem only with these double INNER JOINS that are way too slow.

Comment: Step 1 is surely to switch to InnoDB. It won't improve query speed, but surely we can sacrifice a little speed for improved data integrity.

Comment: I would also remove the ID column on the airport_term table, and instead for the PK on the remaining columns.

Comment: Next, I would remove the GROUP BY clause. Again, it won't help query performance, but at least you will have a comprehensive result.

Comment: And if airport names are UNIQUE, then I would specify that too, or otherwise index them.

Comment: Did you also add an index on `airport`.`name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to cut down the time by 1/2 using subquery instead of join. It takes 1-2 seconds to run the query. Not ideal, but definitely progress. I would still need to join the hotel in subquery for some filtering, but it's still faster.

Not an expert, but I think it helps that I don't join every hotel to every term, but first filter terms and then just select appropriate hotels instead.

```
SELECT `hotel`.* FROM `hotel` 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `term`.`hotel_ID` FROM `term` 
    INNER JOIN `airport_term` ON airport_term.term_ID=term.ID 
    INNER JOIN `airport` ON airport.ID=airport_term.airport_ID WHERE `airport`.`name` IN ('Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Prague') 
    GROUP BY `term`.`hotel_ID`
) `subquery` ON subquery.hotel_ID=hotel.ID ORDER BY `hotel`.`master_rating` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the problem to its essential components...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hotel;

CREATE TABLE hotel 
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,rating float NOT NULL
);

-- populated with 4096 hotels

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS term;

CREATE TABLE term 
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,hotel_ID int NOT NULL
,KEY (hotel_ID)
);

-- populated with 16384 terms

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport;
CREATE TABLE airport 
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

-- populated with 50 airports

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airport_term;
CREATE TABLE airport_term 
(term_ID INT NOT NULL
,airport_ID INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (term_ID,airport_ID)
);

-- populated with 1403 airport_term pairs


 SELECT DISTINCT h.* 
  FROM hotel h
  JOIN term t 
    ON t.hotel_ID = h.ID 
  JOIN airport_term ta 
    ON ta.term_ID = t.ID 
  JOIN airport a
    ON a.ID = ta.airport_ID 
 WHERE a.name IN ('Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Prague') 
 ORDER 
    BY h.ID 
     , h.rating DESC

-- returns 72 rows in zero seconds, as follows (condensed):

+-----+------------+
| ID  | rating     |
+-----+------------+
|  45 |  0.0494382 |
|  57 |   0.637326 |
...
| 480 |   0.837546 |
| 481 |   0.860047 |
| 486 |  0.0134837 |
...
| 770 |   0.995263 |
| 787 |   0.590259 |
| 801 |   0.102722 |
| 808 |   0.874417 |
| 813 |   0.217236 |
...
| 885 |   0.405265 |
| 887 |   0.437901 |
| 897 |   0.720929 |
| 901 |    0.84102 |
| 903 |   0.139152 |
| 908 |   0.600746 |
| 909 |   0.502444 |
| 992 |   0.631546 |
+-----+------------+

EXPLAIN 
SELECT DISTINCT h.* 
  FROM hotel h
  JOIN term t 
    ON t.hotel_ID = h.ID 
  JOIN airport_term ta 
    ON ta.term_ID = t.ID 
  JOIN airport a
    ON a.ID = ta.airport_ID 
 WHERE a.name IN ('Vienna', 'Berlin', 'Prague') 
 ORDER 
    BY h.ID 
     , h.rating DESC

+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ta    | index  | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL               | 1403 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID,name     | PRIMARY | 8       | test.ta.airport_ID |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID,hotel_ID | PRIMARY | 8       | test.ta.term_ID    |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,ID          | PRIMARY | 8       | test.t.hotel_ID    |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Try that with bigger size: 290k terms, 200k airport_terms. I don't see difference between my previous code and this. Just smaller database and use of DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY.

Comment: I removed ID from airport_term - no visible performance benefit, but it is better that way.

Comment: @AlanMcklin So the PK on (term_ID,airport_ID) offered no tangible benefit? Oh, well, time to upgrade the processor.

Comment: I can't add PRIMARY KEY on these... There are multiple duplicate values. Term can have multiple airports. Error #1062

Comment: Terms can have multiple airports, but they can't have the same airport twice. If they can, then that's not presently reflected in your data model

Comment: They can't. I don't see however, how that affects PK. Term can have multiple airports and airport can be in multiple terms. That means no unique values in both fields and no primary key.

Comment: On the contrary, it means that the combination of both columns is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query and where I would expect the optimizer to bottleneck, try adding the following index.

```
ALTER TABLE airport_term
ADD INDEX (airport_ID, term_ID)
```

As your query currently is, it is likely looking up the `airport` table first, getting the `airport_ID` and then having to slog through every single record on the `airport_term` term, because it has no way to quickly find the `term_ID` from the `airport_ID`.

This index should radically improve that part of the query by allowing quick lookup of the `term_ID` from the `airport_ID` among those 200k records.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot see the used datatypes from your tables, so its a short answer:

You are only selecting data from your Hotel table, so:

1. there is no need for a group by
2. there is no need for an inner join, use a  left join.

And:

1. You are ordering by rating, try making that an index.
2. Where name IN, possible speed boost by using: Where airport.name='Vienna'

Comment: there is no need for an inner join, use a left join. - eh?

Comment: There are multiple terms for one hotel. I need to group by, otherwise I get duplicates of hotel.  Adding index and Where airport.name = "" didnt help at all in performance.

Comment: @Strawberry; the result requested is only on the first table; i.e. Hotel. I'm thaught that a left join would be more sufficcient. If you have documentation saying otherwise; i would be happy to read.
@Alan Mcklin No, there's no need for a group by, you only want distinct hotel values? use DISTINCT.

Comment: Unfortunately, your thinking is 180 degrees mistaken. See the manual, or any introductory guide to joins, or a (more advanced) guide to query efficiency.

Comment: @Garytje DISTINCT is slower than Group by in this instance and does the same thing.